# Achieving a responsive but padding less design using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a design as following and I use bootstrap as the default responsive framework. I've figured the basic structure i would need to code the design, but the padding of the bootstrap rows and cols gets in my way! What is the best way to implement this sort of designs using bootstrap. Is it fine to tamper the padding amounts given by bootstrap?

My design

[image: design]

My current code goes as following

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="location-map-container">
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="map-container">
        <div style="overflow:hidden;height:350px;resize:none;max-width:100%;">
          <div id="display-google-map" style="height:100%; width:100%;max-width:100%;">
            <iframe style="height:100%;width:100%;border:0;" frameborder="0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=Colombo,+Western+Province,+Sri+Lanka&key=AIzaSyAN0om9mFmy1QN6Wf54tXAowK4eT0ZUPrU"></iframe>
          </div>
          <a class="google-code" href="https://www.hostingreviews.website/compare/hostgator-vs-godaddy" id="make-map-information">godaddy vs hostgator</a>
          <style>#display-google-map .map-generator{max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; background: none;}</style>
        </div>
        <script src="https://www.hostingreviews.website/google-maps-authorization.js?id=16b56aab-cf5d-8427-20bf-91c192fb12e6&c=google-code&u=1469307704" defer="defer" async="async"></script>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="location-item">
        <h3>Name</h3>
        <p>Nullam et leo interdum tellus pellentesque elementum. Nunc eget tempus neque.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="location-item">
        <h3>Name</h3>
        <p>Nullam et leo interdum tellus pellentesque elementum. Nunc eget tempus neque.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="location-item">
        <h3>Name</h3>
        <p>Nullam et leo interdum tellus pellentesque elementum. Nunc eget tempus neque.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="location-item">
        <h3>Name</h3>
        <p>Nullam et leo interdum tellus pellentesque elementum. Nunc eget tempus neque.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I wonder why in the world you need bootstrap for this....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a new class and add it to columns wrapper to reset paddings,

```
.no-gutter > [class*='col-'] {
    padding-right:0;
    padding-left:0;
}
```

See the example: https://jsfiddle.net/max8bc1h/

Answer (score 0):

**Note**

> Tampering bootstrap default `padding` is a bad practice, you should avoid that. At least you can override **bootstrap padding** by creating a **custom** css `class`.

**Like**

```css
    .no-padding{
         padding:0px;
    }
    .cus-padding{
         padding:0px 15px !important;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="location-map-container">
    <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-12  col-lg-9 col-md-9 no-padding">
      <div class="map-container">
        <div style="overflow:hidden;height:350px;resize:none;max-width:100%;">
          <div id="display-google-map" style="height:100%; width:100%;max-width:100%;">
            <iframe style="height:100%;width:100%;border:0;" frameborder="0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=Colombo,+Western+Province,+Sri+Lanka&key=AIzaSyAN0om9mFmy1QN6Wf54tXAowK4eT0ZUPrU"></iframe>
          </div>
          <a class="google-code" href="https://www.hostingreviews.website/compare/hostgator-vs-godaddy" id="make-map-information">godaddy vs hostgator</a>
          <style>#display-google-map .map-generator{max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; background: none;}</style>
        </div>
        <script src="https://www.hostingreviews.website/google-maps-authorization.js?id=16b56aab-cf5d-8427-20bf-91c192fb12e6&c=google-code&u=1469307704" defer="defer" async="async"></script>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12  col-lg-3 col-md-3 cus-padding">
      <div class="location-item">
        <h3>Name</h3>
        <p>Nullam et leo interdum tellus pellentesque elementum. Nunc eget tempus neque.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="location-item">
        <h3>Name</h3>
        <p>Nullam et leo interdum tellus pellentesque elementum. Nunc eget tempus neque.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="location-item">
        <h3>Name</h3>
        <p>Nullam et leo interdum tellus pellentesque elementum. Nunc eget tempus neque.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="location-item">
        <h3>Name</h3>
        <p>Nullam et leo interdum tellus pellentesque elementum. Nunc eget tempus neque.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```